# how to find out max of a field for two different conditions in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table EMPDATA with the following data:

```
EntityId    MeetDate    SourceCode  Status
1           06.11.2017   AB          FNL
1           05.2.2018    AB          NO
1           09.3.2018    AB          FNL
3           07.12.2016   AB          FNL
3           09.2.2015    AB          FNL
3           07.8.2014    IU          FNL
3           08.7.2017    IU          FNL
```

Conditions :

1) `MeetDate` Column will be split in two columns in the output

1a) `LastDate`: This will be the latest `Meetdate` for `SourceCode`
    ‘AB’ and status ‘FNL’.

1b) `InterimDate`: This will be the latest `Meetdate` for `SourceCode` ‘IU’ which has occurred after the latest `Meetdate` for `SourceCode` ‘AB’ and `Status` ‘FNL’.

For records with no IU sourcecode interimdate will be null.

That is: Output will be as follows:

```
EntityId    LastDate    InterimDate 
1           09.3.2018      NULL          
3           07.12.2016    08.7.2017
```

Comment: Have u tried anything?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve the expected output using *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT EntityId,
       MAX(CASE 
              WHEN SourceCode = 'AB' AND status = 'FNL' THEN MeetDate 
           END) AS LastDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SourceCode = 'IU' THEN MeetDate END) AS InterimDate          
FROM mytable
GROUP BY EntityId
```

This query implements all logic described in the OP except for:

- `InterimDate` ... which has occurred after the latest `Meetdate` for `SourceCode` ‘AB’ and Status ‘FNL’.

You can implement this using a `CTE` so that the code looks cleaner:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT EntityId,
       MAX(CASE 
              WHEN SourceCode = 'AB' AND status = 'FNL' THEN MeetDate 
           END) AS LastDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SourceCode = 'IU' THEN MeetDate END) AS InterimDate          
FROM mytable
GROUP BY EntityId
)
SELECT LastDate, 
       CASE 
          WHEN InterimDate > LastDate THEN InterimDate
       END AS InterimDate
FROM CTE
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/26f2e/9)

Comment: Hi Giorgos, Many Thanks for your response. Can you please explain the solution. It would be very helpful if you can let me know if there are any other way to accomplish this. Like joins, subqueries or the analytical functions.

Comment: @PGupta The query uses basic conditonal aggregation logic: `MAX` operates on `MeetDate` based on conditions defined by `CASE` expressions. This query is the cleanest I can think of for your use case scenario.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I have one more question if I need to left join the  output of this CTE with another table will that be possible? What is the solution in that case.

Comment: @PGupta Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem. The answer to your question is yes, the CTE can be used like a normal table and you can join another table to it.

Comment: I need another help from you. I am struggling with this since a long time now.

Comment: @PGupta This page is about the question you originally asked. If you have another question then try writing another post.

Comment: EntityId Eligibility MeetDate SourceCode Status
1            Y            06.11.2017            AB FNL
1            Y           05.2.2018            AB NO
1            N             09.3.2018            AB FNL
3            Y              07.12.2016     AB FNL
3            N                  09.2.2015     AB FNL
3            Y                07.8.2014           IU FNL
3            Y                08.7.2017           IU FNL
BDt: If Eligibility corresponding to the LastDate in Step a is ‘Y’ the BDt=Meetdate+6.if Eligibility ‘N’ the BDt=Meetdate+4
Kindly help me with this as well plz

Comment: This question is related to the previous itself.

Comment: @PGupta I'm afraid Stack Overflow doesn't work this way. You have posted a question and I tried to answer this specific question that you asked. You have now modified the requirements and ask me to answer this as well. This would result to confusion for other readers of this post. Please try to write a separate question with the exact requirement that you have.

Answer (score 2):

@Anita, I coudn't provide answer your latest question "**Finding max date with different conditions [duplicate]**" due to set as duplicate question. You can try the following query

```
SELECT B.EntityId,A.Eligibility,A.MeetDate,B.LastDate, B.InterimDate, 
(CASE WHEN A.Eligibility=1 THEN DATEADD(MONTH,6,A.MeetDate) ELSE DATEADD(Month,4,A.MeetDate) END) AS BusinessDate FROM StackTable A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT EntityId,
       MAX(CASE 
              WHEN SourceCode = 'AB' AND status = 'FNL' THEN MeetDate 
           END) AS LastDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SourceCode = 'IU' THEN MeetDate END) AS InterimDate

FROM StackTable
GROUP BY EntityId) B
ON A.EntityId=B.EntityId AND A.MeetDate = B.LastDate
```