# Finding max date with different conditions

Tags: sql-server

```
EntityId    Eligibility MeetDate    SourceCode  Status
1             Y           06.11.2017      AB    FNL
1             Y            05.2.2018     AB      NO
1             N            09.3.2018    AB      FNL
3             Y            07.12.2016   AB      FNL
3             N             09.2.2015   AB      FNL
3             Y             07.8.2014   IU      FNL
3             Y              08.7.2017  IU      FNL
```

Conditions :

1. MeetDate Column will be split in two columns in the output

   a) LastDate: This will be the latest Meetdate for sourcecode ‘AB’ and status ‘FNL’---- accomplished in the previous part

   b) InterimDate: This will be the latest Meetdate for sourcecode ‘IU’ which has occurred after the latest meetdate for sourcecode ‘AB’ and status ‘FNL’. For records with no IU sourcecode interimdate will be null---- accomplished in the previous part

   c) BusinessDate: If the Eligibility corresponding to the LastDate selected in Step a is ‘Y’ the BusinessDate field will be Meetdate+6 months. In case the Eligibility corresponding to the LastDate selected in Step a is ‘N’ the BusinessDate field will be Meetdate+4 months -- new part. While implementing this logic will be changed. New joins and rules are required to be implemented.

That is:
Output will be as follows:

```
EntityId    LastDate    InterimDate BusinessDate
1            09.3.2018      NULL       09-04-2018
3            07.12.2016    08.7.2017    07-06-2017
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question you asked yesterday - instead of re-posting, please take the time to improve and clarify the initial question.

Comment: @StuartLC This is not a duplicate question. I have added the column Eligibility in the table. The field eligibility is required for the computation of BusinessDate. And the inclusion of this field will change the query. New joins are required to be implemented for successfully computing all the values. Kindly help me in this,

Comment: It seems you have an additional answer to your updated question in the [original thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49220082/314291)